# update Global Var From LocationListener

Tags: android, variables, global

I have created a class which holds global vars:

```
public class GlobalVar extends Application{

    private XData xData;

    public XData getxData ()     
    {         
        return xData;     
    }     

    public void setXdata  (XData Xdata)     
    {
        this.xData = xData;                
    } 
}
```

When I access this class using `(GlobalVar)getApplicationContext()` from the activities of my application its fine, but when I want to access it from another class (in this case its `LocationListener`), I cant use `(GlobalVar)getApplicationContext()`

How could I access the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the Singleton pattern on your GlobalVar class. And access them directly without getter/setter is recommended on android (read the [performance guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html)).

You could also just make your xData variable static and than you can access it directly from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
Context.getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
GlobalVar gv = (GlobalVar) getApplication()
```

from any `Activity` in your code.

For more info refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()

Comment: Its not an activity, its a class that implements LocationListener.